# What would be the stored procedure for searching multiple items from the same search button?

Tags: jquery, sql

Planning same search button for searching name, address etc while giving input

Comment: explain your situation with an example

Comment: What is the relationship between StoreDProcedure and JQuery tag ?

Answer (score 0):

User **LIKE** with **OR**

DECLARE @Search varchar(20)

SET @Search = ''

SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE

NAME **LIKE** '%' + @Search + '%'

**OR**

ADDRESS  **LIKE** '%' + @Search + '%'